# what are the differences between the verb: "flick" and "flip"?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-meaning, difference

[flick](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flick_1?q=flick)

> 1-[transitive] flick something + adv./prep. to hit something lightly
>   with a sudden quick movement, especially using your finger and thumb
>   together, or your hand
>
> She flicked the dust off her collar.
>
> The horse was flicking flies away with its tail.
>
> James flicked a peanut at her.
>
> Please don't flick ash on the carpet!
>
> The striker flicked the ball into the back of the net. She snatched up
>   her briefcase and flicked it open.
>
> 2- ​[intransitive, transitive] to move or make something move with
>   sudden quick movements
>
> - adv./prep. The snake's tongue flicked out.
>
> Her eyes flicked from face to face.
>
> flick something (+ adv./prep.) He lifted his head, flicking his hair
>   off his face.
>
> The horse moved off, flicking its tail.

---

[flip](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/flip_1?q=flip)

> 1- ​[intransitive, transitive] to turn over into a different position
>   with a sudden quick movement; to make something do this
>
> The plane flipped and crashed.
>
> (figurative) She felt her heart flip (= with excitement, etc.).
>
> flip something (+ adj.) He flipped the lid open and looked inside the
>   case.
>
> 3 - [transitive] to throw something somewhere with a sudden quick
>   movement, especially using your thumb and/or fingers SYNONYM toss
>
> flip a coin They flipped a coin to decide who would get the ticket.
>
> flip something + adv./prep. He flipped the keys onto the desk.

---

[This Youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mboODU0PMuc) shows a "**hair flick**" and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Q6RB-Q5h9cw) shows a "**hair flip**". The 2 actions are **almost the same**.

what are the differences between the verb: "**flick**" and "**flip**"?

Comment: As the definitions say, _flick_ often refers to the action of holding a bent finger with your thumb and suddenly releasing it so that it strikes something sharply, and _flip_ often means to turn something over - but they can also often be interchangeable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words have, as you observed, significant overlap in meaning. Within that similar area of a sudden, quick movement, 'flip' generally refers to a movement which includes a rotational element; flipping an object changes its orientation. A flick does not emphasize this element (though it may still be present). As Kate noted, 'flick' also refers to a specific action of using the thumb and a finger to strike an object.

In addition, 'flip' is sometimes used in a more abstract sense for a reversal, for example of an opinion ("his views on the senator flipped after the debate") or of a trait with two modes or possibilities; the not operator, which converts true to false and vice versa, can be described as "flipping" the bit.